# php fpm outbound socket

Tags: php, php-fpm

how to set PHP-FPM (> 7) to bind outgoing connection to  specific socket/ip  ?
i know there is  pool directive

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:port
```

but its for incoming connections but what with outgoing ?

Comment: The listen directives have nothing to do with outbound connections.

Comment: @EEAA so how set outbound socket ?

Comment: With your operating system's network stack.

Comment: @EEAA you refer to iptables ? most of programs could bind outbound/inbound sockets ( eg privoxy, dante, nginx, dovecot, postfix)    php-fpm cant ?

Comment: No, you're discussing routing, so your routing tables need to be set correctly.

Comment: how i route traffic  per process / socket (php-fpm)?? this is a socket layer  so app should handle it and see for example https://serverfault.com/questions/128357/routing-application-traffic-through-specific-interface as i said i need  to mark packets first to route  so iptables !

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this at the cURL level by binding a cURL instance to an interface:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, 'x.x.x.x');
```

Comment: but what when i use PDO ?   is a cURL a layer for network request thru PDO?